# Calculating area bounded by $y=f(x)$ in an interval when $f(x)$ is directly not given

Tags: calculus, integration, area

$A_{4}$=Area bounded by $y=f(x)$ from $x=1$, to $x=3$, where f(x) satisfies:

$$\int_0^1(x-f(x))f(x)dx=\frac{1}{12}$$

---

My guess about this problem is that basically we have to extract $f(x)$ from the given information. And then simply calculate the area by integrating it from $x=1$ to $x=3$ but I'm not able to understand how to get an idea about $f(x)$ from the given condition.

Also, maybe we have to find an approximate answer, since the problem finally asks for

$[A_4]$ ,where [.] is the Greatest Integer Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$0\leq\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x}{2}-f(x)\right)^2dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx-\int_{0}^{1}(x-f(x))f(x)dx=\frac{1}{12}-\int_{0}^{1}(x-f(x))f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

As shown by Äres, any $f\in L^2(0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)(x-f(x))\,dx=\frac{1}{12}$ is almost-everywhere equal to $\frac{x}{2}$ on $(0,1)$. On the other hand this tells us pretty much nothing about $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,dx$, since the values of $f(x)$ over $(1,3)$ are not constrained by the previous identity.